# pthread assignment output error

Tags: c++, pthreads

I have a problem with an assignment:

I have an array coordinate  A of 10000 points in the xyz space and a starting cube with center 0.5,0.5,0.5 and each side has 1 length. 
The cube contains all 10k points
Then the cube will split into 8 same smaller cubes and each one of them will contain a smaller portion of the 10k points.

So the main thread will spawn 8 threads, one for each cube, find the center of each cube according to num_child(*see explanation bellow) and calculate how many points it contains.
In each thread I create a temporary struct to do the calculations and then i push the struct to the global vector.

(*for example a 2d box with center at 0.5,0.5 will split into 4: a(0.25,0.25),b(0.75,0.25),c(0.75,0.25),b(0.75,0.75))

When I run the program, the output I get is "10000 240 240 240 240 240 240 240 240", which is wrong. If I run the program in gdb and step through the code the result is correct.

Any points on what might be wrong? If you require more explanation on any part of the code please tell me...

Thank you for your time

PS:You will need the -std=c++11 -pthread flags to compile. I know that C++11 has builtin threads but the point of the assignment is to be done in pthreads.

UPDATE: I did some poking in the code and I found out that all of the boxes have the same center (0.75,0.75,0.75). Also I set a breakpoint in gdb on "case 0" but it never breaks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

#define N 10000
#define S 20

typedef struct Box{
    int level, child[8], n;
    float center[3];
}Box;

static double A[N][3]; //Coordinate array
std::vector<Box> box;

//initializing mutexes and a variable to hold the running threads
int running_threads;
pthread_mutex_t running_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

//arguments structer
 struct arg_struct{;
    int num_child,level;
};


void *create_child(void *arguments){

    Box temp;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&running_mutex);
    arg_struct *args=(arg_struct*)arguments;
    int num_child=args->num_child;
    temp.level=args->level;
    float akmi=1/pow(2,args->level);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&running_mutex);

    float d=(0.5/pow(2,temp.level));

    switch (num_child){
    case 0:
        temp.center[0]=0.5-d;
        temp.center[1]=0.5-d;
        temp.center[2]=0.5-d;
        break;
    case 1:
        temp.center[0]=0.5+d;
        temp.center[1]=0.5-d;
        temp.center[2]=0.5-d;
        break;
    case 2:
        temp.center[0]=0.5-d;
        temp.center[1]=0.5+d;
        temp.center[2]=0.5-d;
        break;
    case 3:
        temp.center[0]=0.5+d;
        temp.center[1]=0.5+d;
        temp.center[2]=0.5-d;
        break;
    case 4:
        temp.center[0]=0.5-d;
        temp.center[1]=0.5-d;
        temp.center[2]=0.5+d;
        break;
    case 5:
        temp.center[0]=0.5+d;
        temp.center[1]=0.5-d;
        temp.center[2]=0.5+d;
        break;
    case 6:
        temp.center[0]=0.5-d;
        temp.center[1]=0.5+d;
        temp.center[2]=0.5+d;
        break;
    case 7:
        temp.center[0]=0.5+d;
        temp.center[1]=0.5+d;
        temp.center[2]=0.5+d;
        break;
    }

    int number=0;


    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        if ((A[i][0]>=(temp.center[0]-akmi/2)) && (A[i][0]<=(temp.center[0]+akmi/2))){
            if((A[i][1]>=temp.center[1]-akmi/2)&&(A[i][1]<=temp.center[1]+akmi/2)){
                if((A[i][2]>=temp.center[2]-akmi/2)&&(A[i][2]<=temp.center[2]+akmi/2)){
                        number++;
                    }
            }
        }
    }


    pthread_mutex_lock(&running_mutex);
    temp.n=number;
    box.push_back(temp);
    running_threads--;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&running_mutex);

}

int main(){
    //Generate random A array
    const double pi = 3.14159265358979323846;
    std::default_random_engine rnd;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0.0, 1.0);

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        double z = dist(rnd);
        double t = (pi/2.0)*dist(rnd);
        double r = sqrt(1.0-z*z);

        A[i][0]=r*cos(t);
        A[i][1]=r*sin(t);
        A[i][2]=z;
    }
    std::cout<<"\nCoordinates array completed\n";
///////

    Box temp;
    arg_struct *args=new arg_struct;
    pthread_t threads[8];

    //Original Box
    temp.level=0;
    temp.n=N;
    temp.center[0]=0.5;
    temp.center[1]=0.5;
    temp.center[2]=0.5;
    box.push_back(temp);

    //Starting threads
    for (int i=0;i<8;i++){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&running_mutex);
        args->level=1;
        args->num_child=i;
        running_threads++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&running_mutex);
        pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,create_child,(void*)args);
    }

    while(running_threads>0){

    }

    for (int i=0;i<9;i++){
        std::cout<<box[i].n<<"\n";
    }

    return 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not gonna fix your problem, but if I'm not mistaken you don't control race conditions on `running_threads` properly when waiting for it to become 0. I would do something along the lines of

```
pthread_mutex_lock
while (running_threads>0){
  pthread_cond_wait
}
pthread_mutex_unlock
```

And then have the threads call `pthread_cond_signal` after `running_threads--;`

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the same struct to all thread functions.
If you're unlucky you will modify its members in one iteration before the thread from the previous iteration has started.